# What's a good method to trigger apache restart after .deb installation?

Tags: apache, triggers, deb, dpkg

I have several custom .debs that I've built.  They all depend on apache and after upgrade of any package apache needs to be restarted.

Restarting apache naively from the postinst I get a restart for each package I upgrade, which is really slow.  Does anyone know if there's a good way to avoid that?  Dpkg triggers seems to be the right approach but I can't seem to find much in the way of documentation.  Does apache define its own trigger to activate.  If so, how do I call it?

Comment: I'm assuming this was one of the resources that you already looked at (and decided wasn't sufficient):  http://www.seanius.net/blog/2009/09/dpkg-triggers-howto/

Comment: I had a look at that but, although it mentions apache, it doesn't give details on how to do it (and the git link is broken).  I was hoping that it's such a common thing to want to do that someone might know of an elegant solution (like apache providing a trigger for the purpose).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, dpkg triggers would be the right approach here. And no, I don't believe that there is any preexisting trigger-fu to solve this problem for you.

At its most simple, your setup might consist of something like the following:

- Some common package, on which all of your apache-using debs will Depend. Let's call it "apache-coordination".
- apache-coordination's `DEBIAN/triggers` file should contain a line like `interest apache-coordination-reload`.
- apache-coordination's `postinst` should handle the case where it gets called with the argument "`triggered`" and where "`apache-coordination-reload`" is somewhere in the second argument, by performing the actual apache reload or restart (ideally through `invoke-rc.d` or something similar, so that runlevels are respected).
- Your other packages should activate the `apache-coordination-reload` trigger when appropriate. This could be done by shipping `DEBIAN/triggers` files for each of them containing `activate apache-coordination-reload`.

Comment: It would be useful to link to the documentation on triggers: http://sources.debian.net/src/dpkg/stable/doc/triggers.txt/